# Manipulate the effect of varying the level of flattening on a TreeForm expression

Tags: functions, manipulate

I want to visualize how `Flatten` works and have a slider that changes the level of flattening.

Here is the list of lists I'm using and Flatten function.

```
bifurcate[list_] := Nest[Partition[#, 2] &, list, Floor[Log[2, Length[list1]]]]

(structured = bifurcate[list1])//TreeForm

structured // Flatten[#, n] &
```

I want to be able to change the value of `n` from 1 to 3 with a step of 1,

However,

```
TreeForm[Flatten[structured, n]], {n, 0, 3}
```

doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't `bifurcate` use `Length[list]` rather than `Length[list1]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think first clean up `structured`.  Then

```
Manipulate[TreeForm[Flatten[structured, n]], {n, Range[0,3]}]
```

will give the `TreeForm` for `n` in `{0,1,2,3}`.  Just `Range[3]` for `n` in `{1,2,3}`.  This is not a "slider" but discrete choices since `n` is an integer.

Comment: For a slider, just use `{n, 0, 3, 1}` instead of `{n, Range[0,3]}`.